# Cordova Media plugin - Load stream after hours

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, media, internet-radio

For a long time i m trying to solve problem with cordova media plugin...
All i want is to play internet radio stream on button press (play)
This is my code:
app.js

```
var mmedia;
function playAudio(url) {
    mmedia = new Media(url,
    function () {   
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");   
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
    }
    );
    // Play audio
    mmedia.play();
}
```

index.html

```
  <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="playAudio('http://streaming.tdiradio.com:9000/');" />
```

But all i get is silence...And few hours later radio just starts playing..
Hours after app was closed (i didn't release media though)...

---

I'm using Android 4.4.2 on my phone..
On Ripple works just fine without 1s of delay..

What is this about? And what is the best way to solve this?